# Macron in pandoc markdown. (Mh\={a}v\={\i}ra)

Tags: accents, pandoc, markdown

I'm using `pandoc` markdown to generate PDF, and I cannot get it to accept my special characters.

For example, I want to include `Mah\={a}v\={\i}ra` in my document to place macrons over the appropriate letters. When I publish:

```
pandoc -o mydoc.pdf mydoc.md
```

I my document contains `Mah={a}v={i}ra`. The dot has been stripped from the `i`, as I requested by using `\i`, but the `\=` was just converted to `=`.

A few tests with similar accent characters is revealing the same problem.

How can I get macron accents into my document?

Comment: Pandoc is only on-topic for us when there is a strong (La)TeX link: it's not the case in the question as phrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when `pandoc` finds something which looks like a latex command (i.e: the escape char `\` followed by letters, and possibly several arguments in braces, such as in `\emph{xxx}`) it passes the command and its arguments without processing directly to the generated `.tex` file. When the output format is not latex related, it ignores the complete command and its arguments (e.g: in the html ouptput).

In your case `\i` has the structure of a tex command, but `\=` does not because it does not contain any letter (and apparently `pandoc` does not support active chars). This explains the result you got.

Possible workarounds:

1. "Hacking" the tex output. You can define in your latex template (or even inside your pandoc document) the following command:

   ```
   \def\passthrulatex#1{#1}
   ```

   Then, when you use this command as part of your pandoc document, the command *and its argument* will be passed without changes to the resulting `.tex` file. So, you can for example write `\passthrulatex{Mah\={a}v\={\i}ra}` and get the desired output in the `pdf`. However, if you try to produce `html` this whole command (and its argumet) will dissapear in the html version, so this solution is not optimal.
2. Using unicode. Instead of using tex accent primitives, input directly the unicode chars in the pandoc source. This is IMHO a more sensible solution, since after all pandoc source should be as independent as possible of the final format (and thus of tex). In this case you would write directly `Mahāvīra` in your pandoc source, and save that file with utf8 encoding.

   Pandoc will pass the unicode directly to the output, so it will work for html output, and also for `pdf`  output if the latex template used is prepared to deal with utf8. Pandoc's default template comes with utf8 support, so it should work out of the box. You can even use `pandoc` to generate the intermediate `tex` file and then "manually" compile that file with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` to ensure full unicode support.

Comment: Thank you! Based on a previous deleted comment (yours?), I went the unicode route. A couple minutes refreshing myself on how to make the characters in vim, and a couple more minutes updating my publishing script to include --latex-engine=xelatex, and I have some beautifully accented output. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, the comment was mine, but I decided to expand it into a full answer. Glad to help.

Comment: A simpler hack worked for me: `\relax{}` with the letter commands in the braces.